# Generating power from fruit

Tags: electrical-engineering, design, power, renewable-energy

Is it possible to generate power from fruit juice, using a device with a simple circuit which charges a battery using juice from fresh oranges?

If so what would be the ratio between emf emitted and juice from orange?

if the device used rechargeable cells charged by the orange juice, would there be enough force to cut oranges automatically with a small blade connected to a battery powered motor?

I am hoping to collect and store energy collected from the juice in a rechargeable battery, would this be possible? of so would be energy stored be enough to power a small motor to operate a knife which would cut through the fruit?

the device would cut oranges into quarters at the press of a button, it would use a collection tray beneath the cutting area which collects juice residue from the cutting process and convert this into electrical energy stored in a battery.

Comment: "Potato clocks" will work with many other fruits and veggies:  http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Potato-Clock

Comment: Ferment the juice with yeast, distil the alcohol, burn in a internal or external combustion engine and drive an alternator.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be asking about using fruit juice as the electrolyte of a battery.  Yes, that's possible, but you don't get a lot of power that way.  The power also doesn't just come from the fruit juice.  That's only one of the chemical reactants.  One or both electrodes are the other side of the chemical reactions.

The EMF is a function of the battery chemistry, which means the chemical makeup of the elctrodes and the electrolyte.  No matter how much juice is used, the EMF will be the same for the same electrodes.

The rest of your question confuses force and power, so there is no sensible way to answer it.